# array of Random Images with one function of 2 buttons

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, button

I need to do an array of random image and a one function with two buttons. Example a picture of Pikachu and there is a 2 choices button one is for correct answer and one is for wrong answer and when it is correct the score adds 1 until it meets 10 points, and when its wrong there would be a picture of Pikachu with its trivia. And in every picture there would be a 2 buttons.

This is my code:

```
     <html>
<title>
    Guess the CharToon 
</title>
   <head>
        <LINK rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="F:\ANGELA\MM1\CHARTOON\CSS\chartoon.css">      
        <div id="status" style="padding: 1%;background-color: white;border-radius: 1%;color: black;font-size: 30;font-family: aero; position: absolute;top: 75%;left: 85%;"></div>
      <style>
 body { 
    background: url('F:/ANGELA/MM1/CHARTOON/IMAGES/Easylevel/EL11.jpg') no- repeat center center fixed;

-moz-background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
 } 
</style>
</head>
<p id="puntos"></p>

  <body>
     <script src="F:\ANGELA\MM1\CHARTOON\JS\EL1.js"></script>

       <h1>Who is this <br> character?</h1>

    <form action="RANDEL1.html">
    <button onmousedown="bleep.play()"  id="option3" class="option3" onmouseover="PlaySound('mySound')" onmouseout="StopSound('mySound')" onclick="pikachu()" value="refresh">Pikachu<audio id='mySound' src='D:\angela\MULTIMEDIA TECH\CHARTOON\chartooners\SOUNDS\Pikachu Sms.mp3' ></button>
    </form>
    <form action="TriviaE1Pika.html">
    <button onmouseover="bleep.play()"  id="option4" class="option2">Onix</button>
        <div id="status"></div>
    </form>
    <a href="F:\ANGELA\MM1\CHARTOON\HTML\EASY.html"><img class="back2"src="F:\ANGELA\MM1\CHARTOON\IMAGES\MENU\back.png"></a>


</body>
    <audio src="F:\ANGELA\MM1\CHARTOON\SOUNDS\Main.mp4" autoplay loop hidden>    </audio>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
         function pikachu()
         {
        localStorage["score"]=parseInt(localStorage["score"],10)+1;


        if (localStorage["score"]==10)

            {
                window.location="F:/ANGELA/MM1/CHARTOON/HTML/FSEL1.html" ;
            }

    }
        document.getElementById("puntos").innerHTML=localStorage["score"] +  "/10";
```

Comment: What is wrong? Explain what the code you have provided should does and what it does not.

Comment: My code provided a picture with the buttons. The one button is for the right answer while the other is for the wrong answer. when the user hits the correct button there will be another html with the same code but different picture. and when the user hits the wrong button there will have a trivia html of that picture.

I need to reduce my html. because every question there will have a html. So can it be with every images have 2 buttons one for the correct answer and one for the wrong answer? With just one html? and the images are randomly displaying?